# Python unexpected indent ,but indent is right

Tags: python

Below is my code, simple routine, cannot figure out what is wrong with the indent, but keeps getting complain right after the val=line.strip().split() no matter what I put there...

```
if line.startswith('U'):
    val = line.strip().split()
    print val
```

Comment: Check that you're not mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: think you used tab instead of 4 spaces. Don't mix the both..

Comment: You have probably used `tab` and `space` both to indent. Don't do that. Better to use 4 space as PEP8 convention.

Comment: thanks for all the help~~ yes, it is because mix tab and spaces, thank you all

Answer (score 1):

This line is indented by 4 spaces

```
val = line.strip().split()
```

This one is indented by a TAB

```
print val
```

In many editors (including SO) these appear to be indented the same. It's possible to mix tab and space indenting in Python, but a *really really* bad idea